# How to get cURL to output only HTTP response body (JSON) and no other headers etc

Tags: json, bash, curl

I am using curl in a bash script to fetch the response of a service as below,

```
response=$(curl -isb -H "Accept: application/json" "http://host:8080/some/resource")
```

Service response is of json type and on browser I could perfectly fine response.
However curl response has other unwanted things (such as set-cookie, content-length header in this case) and sometimes the actual response is eaten up.

Here is the output of `echo $response` >

```
 Set-Cookie: rack.session=BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiRWJlY2JiOTE2M2Q1ZWI4NThjMDdi%0AYjRiOWRjMGMxMGEwYTBkMjE3NmJhZDVjYzY4YjY4ZTlmMTE2ZGVkYWE3MTMG%0AOwBGS
SIJY3NyZgY7AEZJIiVhZmQ2MmUyZGMxMzFmOGEwMjg3NDlhNWM3YmVm%0AN2FjNwY7AEZJIg10cmFja2luZwY7AEZ7B0kiFEhUVFBfVVNFUl9BR0VOVAY7%0AAFRJIi00MTc0OGM2MWNkMzljZTYxNzY3ZjU0
Y2I5OTdiYWRkN2MyNTBkYmU4%0ABjsARkkiGUhUVFBfQUNDRVBUX0xBTkdVQUdFBjsAVEkiLWRhMzlhM2VlNWU2%0AYjRiMGQzMjU1YmZlZjk1NjAxODkwYWZkODA3MDkGOwBG%0A--ee97a62095e7d42129
 tontent-Length: 354c8; path=/; HttpOnly
```

This is breaking my response parsing logic.
I have seen this happening intermittently which is weird.

Is there a way to get **"only"** json response from cURL output?
I went through the curl documentation but could not see any thing/ or I could have missed it.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You are specifying the `-i` option:

> **-i**, --include
>
> (HTTP) **Include the HTTP-header in the output**. The HTTP-header includes things like server-name, date of the document, HTTP-version and more...

Simply remove that option from your command line:

```
response=$(curl -sb -H "Accept: application/json" "http://host:8080/some/resource")
```

Comment: True. But strange this is; it works directly from command line. But from bash script it behaves different, I m not able to see anything in the echo response except the letter "t"

Comment: Changed echo "response is $response" from echo $response and now I m able to see the correct response. Dunno why would that be. Thanks!

Comment: One learning is when used inside a command always "quote" a echo variable.. responsenew=$(echo "$response" | grep "abc")

Comment: Rishi, the quotes around $response avoid breaking the contents at new lines and spaces

Answer (score 54):

I was executing a get request an also want to see just the response and nothing else, seems like magic is done with **-silent,-s** option.

From the curl man page:

> -s, --silent
> Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.

Below the examples:

```
curl -s "http://host:8080/some/resource"
curl --silent "http://host:8080/some/resource"
```

Using custom headers

```
curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" "http://host:8080/some/resource"
```

Using POST method with a header

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://host:8080/some/resource" -d '{ "myBean": {"property": "value"}}'
```

You can also customize the output for specific values with **-w**, below the options I use to get just response codes of the curl:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "http://host:8080/some/resource"
```