# How To Prevent Redirect After Succesfully Login With CURL in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I had a problem regarding redirect after I had successfully log in using CURL.

My CURL command:

**curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in -d '{"user": {"email": "admin@admin.com", "password": "abc12345"}}' -i**

My CURL Response:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-Xss-Protection: 1;
>   mode=block X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Location:
>   http://localhost:3000/ Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>   Cache-Control: no-cache X-Request-Id:
>   15d20863-7666-4c8a-8de1-ec8de97e5e53 X-Runtime: 0.109029 Server:
>   WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-05-08) Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 03:52:04
>   GMT Content-Length: 88 Connection: Keep-Alive Set-Cookie:
>   request_method=POST; path=/ Set-Cookie:
>   _stuckplaces_session=UWpsUlRhZ0pPdmxOcXlpa3Bpd1ZRbDRGOE1GUXErMnQ1MHNSQUxYMzN2V3lROHJUbU5BWTZJZTJERlVxTTFPajJub2grMWRnK05zTnNGMXN2K09DU1NFdEJUblliZlJuOUdlWTZOakZ3ai85ZjdqVTJqa0pzcEcrUFNTWjIzc2dFc2lOMm1ZaFdIUG56UHU5ZU9NNGliSmUyNmNIdk81MWQ5bXJyWVpXbGtDVGtVeEFzdS9PYk5IaDMvSUkxZnpjaEZ2K3hmQU9FcTI4dTQ3UldwVDNuZjhlTDRKMiszZTdSS01WMzZmNi9yb21Zei85N2laZ2VQOWI3eDlkTVkzQS0tT1JNbDdKbng5cVdaT0hYRFFIc0JCQT09--971fd40b128844eb52699bd18b54ed31f2bf162f;
>   path=/; HttpOnly
>
> You are being redirected.

And this is log that I got in terminal:

> Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2015-07-30 11:52:03 +0800
>   Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as */*   Parameters:
>   {"user"=>{"email"=>"admin@admin.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
>   "session"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"admin@admin.com",
>   "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}   User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".*
>   FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC
>   LIMIT 1  [["email", "admin@admin.com"]]    (0.1ms)  begin transaction 
>   SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = ?,
>   "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE
>   "users"."id" = ?  [["last_sign_in_at", "2015-07-30 03:51:57.486750"],
>   ["current_sign_in_at", "2015-07-30 03:52:04.060786"],
>   ["sign_in_count", 23], ["updated_at", "2015-07-30 03:52:04.061836"],
>   ["id", 6]]    (8.8ms)  commit transaction Redirected to
>   http://localhost:3000/ Completed 302 Found in 105ms (ActiveRecord:
>   9.3ms)

This is my sessions_controller.rb :

> https://gist.github.com/afiq90/2d3f02878cf9c23a03b1

I also had commented **protect_from_forgery with: :exception** in application_controller, if I'm not commented this line, I will got error 422 Unprocessable Entity.

As far as I understand based on the log, I had successfully signed in into rails app using CURL, but the response for CURL is 302 redirect supposedly it should be 200 and returned the token associated with successfully login credentials. I hope someone can help me with this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try looking into this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254064/how-to-get-curl-to-output-only-http-response-body-json-and-no-other-headers-et

Comment: I still cannot get token value after have made changes. @AbdulRahimMohamad

Answer (score 1):

Modify your curl url to

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json
```

If we look at the given gist `https://gist.github.com/afiq90/2d3f02878cf9c23a03b1`
It will take html format and as a response, it will redirect you to root page.