# Get json data with curl

Tags: json, api, curl

I'm trying to get some data (mac adresses more precisely) from a server thank to its API. The data is in json format and I can't have the output that i'm expecting. And by the way I want to redirect the output that i expect (So the json data) towards a file.

For example: i'm doing this :

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET https://internal.mycompany.com/api/install/get_macs.php?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" > mac.txt
```

And the output i get is this:

```
[1] 1308
mo@servertest:~$
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 21 Apr 2021 15:13:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Content-Length: 62
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

[{"mactabwifi":"","mactabwired":"","maccam":"","macnuc":null}]
```

And I have to press enter a second time otherwise it is not doing anything. Once I press enter  I get this:

```
[1]+  Done                    curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET https://internal.mycompany.com/api/install/get_macs.php?token=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Do you have any idea how i can get only the data I need without pressing enter a second time?

And by the way, after all of this, when I'm doing a cat of my file mac.txt, nothing there is nothing..

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254064/how-to-get-curl-to-output-only-http-response-body-json-and-no-other-headers-et/24254142) answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to have your desired output by using this command:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" https://internal.mycompany.com/api/install/get_macs.php?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx > mac.txt
```

Curl defaults to GET HTTP method, and -i option is used to include header in response, otherwise you'll have only body as output.