# Save curl response in a variable in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, curl, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins decalarative pipeline where I am calling some URL via cURL which is returning JSON response. How to catch that JSON in a variable?

Have tried the below code but it's returning entire thing with path and command along with the response

```
environment {
        token = bat(returnStdout: true, script: 'curl https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/login -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\\"username\\" : \\"user\\",\\"password\\" : \\"pwd\\"}"').trim()
        }
```

JSON response

```
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\publish-api>curl https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/login -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"username\" : \"ap-1\",\"password\" : \"Ap5\"}" 
{
  "access_token": "axxxx-5ca2-48eb-9eb3-173c44a811",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "redirectUrl": "/home/"
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24254142/10493338

Comment: Thanks. but the curl command is working fine, it returns JSON only but in Jenkins (with the snippet in question) it includes the command itself in output along with the response

Comment: Can you add the json in the question? Accessing the correct value should be simple if a valid JSON is returned

Comment: added JSON response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [readJson](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) method to get to your wished result. You don't necesseraly have to call it in your environment-block.

```
stage('Curl') {
  steps {
   script {
    def cUrlResponse = bat(returnStdout: true, script: '@curl https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/login -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\\"${env.username}\\" : \\"user\\",\\"${env.password}\\" : \\"pwd\\"}"').trim()
    def responseJson = readJSON text: cUrlResponse 
    def accessToken = responseJson.access_token
    def tokenType = responseJson.token_type
    // do other stuff with the variables
   }
  }
}
```

To exclude the curl command from the output, add @ in front of the script as stated [in the documentation.](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script)

Comment: readJSON text: cUrlResponse  - says invalid JSON. since returnstdOut returns command also in the output, which leads to failure

Comment: The console output shouldn't be an issue. Can you print the response once with echo ${cUrlResponse} please?

Comment: added JSON response2 in question. It was not formatting data in comment so

Comment: You have to add a @ to the returnStdout as stated in the documentation. Then the command itself will be excluded and you should only get the JSON: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script

Comment: Try to add the @ in front of your script, so "@curl ..."